# Are Floor Tom and Low Tom refering to the same drum

Tags: drums

When people use the term "Floor Tom" to refer to the drums which normally has a 3 legged stand

[image]

I am wondering if the term "Low Tom" is another name for "Floor Tom" ???

Answer (score 4):

I think your answer is often true, but it isn't the whole story.

The kit in that picture is definitely the most common setup, but there are other possibilities. It's only a "floor" tom if it is on a stand which sits on the floor—as opposed to the toms that hang from mounts on the kick drum or other paraphernalia. This tom will almost certainly be the lowest in pitch, but it isn't an absolutely essential part of a trap setup. If you have only toms hanging from your kit and no tom on the floor, I think it makes sense to call the lowest one the "low" tom, but not the "floor" tom.

Again, a floor tom is a *very* common part of the setup—the other setups are more likely in a marching band or orchestral situation— and it is all but definitely the lowest pitched when it's there, but I think the distinction is worth making. "Low" and "floor" tom are almost always synonymous, but there are exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

After some research , I found a picture from Google which resolves the issue.

**Floor Tom** is synonymous with **Low Tom**

[image]

Comment: Floor Tom is **not** synonymous with Low Tom

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much toms your set has. If you have 2 stand-toms and 4 hanging ones, they would be commonly referenced as (from low to high):

LoFloor (LFT), HiFloor (HFT), LowTom (LT), LoMidTom (LMT), HiMidTom (HMT), HighTom (HT).

Comment: In case of 1 stand-tom and 2 hanging ones, what would be the equivalent @rhavin? 
LoFloor (LFT), LowTom (LT), HiMidTom (HMT) OR HiFloor (HFT), LoMidTom (LMT), HighTom (HT)?

Comment: Usually FT, LT, HT